# VBA Toggle button hide blanks

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I would like to ask if is there any way to use toggle VBA for hide/unhide? But I need only blank rows depending at one cell.

```
For Each Cell In ARE
If Cell.Value = "" Then Cell.Offset(0, 0).Rows
.Hidden = Not .Hidden
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the `EntireRow` property. See below

```
For Each cell In are
    With cell
    If .Value = "" Then
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End If
    End With
Next
```